# node-mysql changes Date.now() as if we are in 1970

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am using node-mysql. 
I  keep last operation time in miliseconds in db.

Everything is fine however when i monitor the process through node-inspector  timestamp is right but when it is saved into db it turns into this value `2147483647`

Which is equal to `Sun Jan 25 1970 23:31:23 GMT+0300 (MSK)`

Column is formatted as int(20) i cant understand why it happens this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'timestamp' you have is the maximum value for `INT()`, see the mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html).

You should change the column to `BIGINT()` to be able to store timestamps with ms precision.